# Snowflake not sure about query time comparaison

Tags: time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to calculate the attrition comparing the last month from the selected.
In this case i want to know the lost clients from 2020-12-01 to 2021-01-01.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT("Client Ref"),"Zone","Market Place","Report Period"
FROM    "REPORT_DB"."PBI"."Revenue" d
WHERE   "Report Period" ='2020-12-01' AND "Market Place" ='UK' AND "Client Ref" IS NOT NULL 
AND
NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  "Client Ref"
        FROM    "REPORT_DB"."PBI"."Revenue" t
        WHERE   "Report Period" ='2021-01-01' AND "Market Place" ='UK' AND "Client Ref" IS NOT NULL AND d."Client Ref"=t."Client Ref"
        )
```

Is it the correct way to retrieve it ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by adding a CTE with some dummy data, and changing the column names to all be safe

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    (1,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (1,'a','UK','2021-01-01'),
    (2,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (3,'a','UK','2021-01-01')
    v( Client_Ref, zone, Market_Place, Report_Period)
)
SELECT DISTINCT d.Client_Ref,d.zone,d.Market_Place,d.Report_Period
FROM data AS d
WHERE d.Report_Period ='2020-12-01' AND d.Market_Place ='UK' AND d.Client_Ref IS NOT NULL 
AND
NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  t.Client_Ref
        FROM    data t
        WHERE   t.Report_Period ='2021-01-01' AND t.Market_Place ='UK' AND t.Client_Ref IS NOT NULL AND d.Client_Ref=t.Client_Ref
        );
```

you base form for SQL works and returns:

```
CLIENT_REF  ZONE    MARKET_PLACE    REPORT_PERIOD
2           a       UK              2020-12-01
```

which is the expected results.

This Query is a correlated sub-query, which Snowflake has limited support for. So while this works, as you change the query it might run into the `Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated` error see [SO correlated sub-query question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541592/correlated-subqueries-in-snowflake-doesnt-work).

Thw base query can be written in a  un-correlated form, by using a `LEFT JOIN` and then `WHERE x IS NULL` pattern:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    (1,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (1,'a','UK','2021-01-01'),
    (2,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (3,'a','UK','2021-01-01')
    v( Client_Ref, zone, Market_Place, Report_Period)
)
SELECT DISTINCT d.Client_Ref,d.zone,d.Market_Place,d.Report_Period
FROM data AS d
LEFT JOIN data AS t
    ON t.Report_Period ='2021-01-01' AND t.Market_Place ='UK' AND d.Client_Ref=t.Client_Ref
WHERE d.Report_Period ='2020-12-01' AND d.Market_Place ='UK' AND d.Client_Ref IS NOT NULL 
AND t.Client_Ref IS NULL;
```

which can be rewritten to do some filtering first if your data source has many rows not in the target result range, like so:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    (1,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (1,'a','UK','2021-01-01'),
    (2,'a','UK','2020-12-01'),
    (3,'a','UK','2021-01-01')
    v( Client_Ref, zone, Market_Place, Report_Period)
), wanted_data AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Client_Ref, zone, Market_Place, Report_Period
    FROM data
    WHERE Report_Period BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2021-01-01'
    AND Market_Place ='UK' AND Client_Ref IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT d.Client_Ref,d.zone,d.Market_Place,d.Report_Period
FROM wanted_data AS d
LEFT JOIN wanted_data AS t
    ON t.Report_Period ='2021-01-01'AND d.Client_Ref=t.Client_Ref
WHERE d.Report_Period ='2020-12-01' 
AND t.Client_Ref IS NULL;
```

But for the life of me, my SQL does not work if I name the columns `"Client Ref"` like you have, so that I cannot answer that part, but this is how you can structure your SQL.